# Data binding in d3 donut chart for tooltips

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm trying to create a donut chart in d3 with smooth transitions and tooltips. The chart is working (in the code snippet seems to be another problem, I haven't figured out yet), but somehow I got the data binding wrong, because in the `mouseEnter` Event `d.data` is undefined.

I tried multiple ways to add the data to the chart, but nothing works...`d.data` is always undefined. I get the correct data through `d.explicitOriginalTarget.__data__`, but I read that `explicitOriginalTarget` should not be used in production.

```js
const margin = 40;
const width = 450;
const height = 450;

const radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2 - margin;
const innerRadius = 120;
const cornerRadius = 8;
const padAngle = 0.01;
const transitionDuration = 2000;
const color = d3.scale.ordinal().range(["#0aa849", "#e3df0b", "#a11f0b"]);

let svg = null;
let gElement = null;
let chartPie = null;
let chartArc = null;
let tooltip = null;

svg = d3.select(`#donut_chart`)
  .append("svg")
  .attr("viewBox", `0 0 ${width} ${height}`);

gElement = svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${width / 2},${height / 2})`);

chartArc = d3.svg.arc()
  .innerRadius(innerRadius)
  .outerRadius(radius)
  .cornerRadius(cornerRadius);

function arcTween(a) {
  var i = interpolate(this._current, a);
  this._current = i(0);
  return function(t) {
    return chartArc(i(t));
  };
}

function onMouseEnter(d) {
  console.log(d.data); // <-- this is undefined
  console.log(d.explicitOriginalTarget.__data__.value); // <-- this works
}

function updateChart(data) {
  chartPie = d3.layout.pie()
    .startAngle(-(Math.PI / 2) * 5)
    .value((d) => d[1])
    .sort(null)
    .padAngle(padAngle)(data, (d) => d[0]);

  gElement
    .selectAll("path")
    .transition()
    .duration(transitionDuration)
    .attrTween("d", arcTween);

  gElement
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(chartPie)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", `donut_chart`)
    .attr("fill", (d) => color(d.data[0]))
    .attr("d", chartArc)
    .each(function(d) {
      this._current = d;
    });

  gElement.on("mouseenter", onMouseEnter);
}

let newData = Object.entries({
  high: 3,
  middle: 4,
  low: 2
})
updateChart(newData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="donut_chart" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `gElement` is bound to `<g>` still, which doesn't have any data attached to it. The parts where you use `(d) => ...` and it works are because you do it after the `.selectAll("path")` which changes the context for further chained methods to point to `<path>` that do have data attached.

Your snippet can be fixed by saving the switched context into a variable for later reuse.

```js
const margin = 40;
const width = 450;
const height = 450;

const radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2 - margin;
const innerRadius = 120;
const cornerRadius = 8;
const padAngle = 0.01;
const transitionDuration = 2000;
const color = d3.scale.ordinal().range(["#0aa849", "#e3df0b", "#a11f0b"]);

let svg = null;
let gElement = null;
let chartPie = null;
let chartArc = null;
let tooltip = null;

svg = d3.select(`#donut_chart`)
  .append("svg")
  .attr("viewBox", `0 0 ${width} ${height}`);

gElement = svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${width / 2},${height / 2})`);

chartArc = d3.svg.arc()
  .innerRadius(innerRadius)
  .outerRadius(radius)
  .cornerRadius(cornerRadius);

function arcTween(a) {
  var i = interpolate(this._current, a);
  this._current = i(0);
  return function(t) {
    return chartArc(i(t));
  };
}

function onMouseEnter(d) {
  console.log(d.data); // <-- this is undefined
}

function updateChart(data) {
  chartPie = d3.layout.pie()
    .startAngle(-(Math.PI / 2) * 5)
    .value((d) => d[1])
    .sort(null)
    .padAngle(padAngle)(data, (d) => d[0]);

  gElement
    .selectAll("path")
    .transition()
    .duration(transitionDuration)
    .attrTween("d", arcTween);

  const paths = gElement
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(chartPie)
    .enter()
    .append("path");
  
  paths
    .attr("class", `donut_chart`)
    .attr("fill", (d) => color(d.data[0]))
    .attr("d", chartArc)
    .each(function(d) {
      this._current = d;
    });

  paths.on("mouseenter", onMouseEnter);
}

let newData = Object.entries({
  high: 3,
  middle: 4,
  low: 2
})
updateChart(newData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="donut_chart" />
```